# While Loop not working in Python

Tags: python

I am struggling on this while loop in python I am trying to make the program continue to repeat itself until it output an lower,upper and digit but it ends as I run the program

```
import random

num = 3
print(num)

message=""

for n in range(num):
    while message =="":
        newnum= random.randint(48,122)           
        if newnum > 47 and newnum < 58:
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)

        elif newnum > 64 and newnum <91:
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)

        elif newnum > 97 and newnum < 123:
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)    

        else:
            newnum -= random.randint(7,10)
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)

if (any(x.isupper() for x in message) and any(x.islower() for x in message)and any(x.isdigit() for x in message)):
    print(message)
else:
    message =""
```

Comment: Your stop condition seems broken. As soon as it enters the first time the while, the message is no longer equals to "". Also, it's always good to make it clear what it is that you are aiming for, as well as the output of the actual code. Maybe even an example of the expected result.

Comment: The expected results i would like to see is the output to be something like 7oV  which contains an lowercase and uppercase and a digit

Comment: What is the value in `message` before the character tests. Please `print(message) before the if tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is mainly ident and the while condition, take a look at my code.

```
import random

num = 3
print(num)

message=""
end = False #set a valid condition to end the program
for n in range(num):
#   while message =="":
    while end == False:
        newnum= random.randint(48,122)           
        if newnum > 47 and newnum < 58:
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)
        elif newnum > 64 and newnum <91:
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)
        elif newnum > 97 and newnum < 123:
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)    

        else:
            newnum -= random.randint(7,10)
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)
        if (any(x.isupper() for x in message) 
             and any(x.islower() for x in message) 
             and any(x.isdigit() for x in message)):

            print(message)
            end=True
#       else:
#           message =""
```

Comment: This code is most relevant to what im looking for however it goes over 3 unless there is a lowercase, uppercase and a digit

Comment: just add a len() condition and reset message if it goes over 3

Comment: `if len(message)>3:
 message=""
else:
 if (any(x.isupper() for x in message)
   and any(x.islower() for x in message)
   and any(x.isdigit() for x in message)):
  print(message)
  end=True`

Answer (score 0):

After the first iteration your message will be != of '', because you will set it to a chr(val).  Thus it will never re-enter in the while loop again and it will just finish the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in wrong indention. Try to use

```
for n in range(num):
    while message =="":
        newnum= random.randint(48,122)           
        if newnum > 47 and newnum < 58:
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)

        elif newnum > 64 and newnum <91:
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)

        elif newnum > 97 and newnum < 123:
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)    

        else:
            newnum -= random.randint(7,10)
            val=chr(newnum)
            val = newnum
            message +=chr(val)

        if (any(x.isupper() for x in message) and any(x.islower() for x in message) and any(x.isdigit() for x in message)):
            print(message)
        else:
            message =""
```